# Using Quartz Jobs With Message Driven Bean

Tags: java, wildfly, java-ee-6, message-driven-bean, quartz

I'm working on migrating a project from Jboss AS6 to Wildfly 18 and I'm running into some issues with message driven beans. I tried following the example here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/jboss-quartz/quartz-2-tutorial-on-jboss-as-7 .
I added the quartz dependencies to my pom and made sure I had a resource adapter defined. When I try to actually deploy my application however it fails with the error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed
- address: ([("deployment" => "Product.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.ra.\"jboss.ra.quartz-ra\"",
        "jboss.ra.quartz-ra"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Product.ear\".\"Product-ejb.jar\".component.UpdateReleasePlansMDB.CREATE is missing [jboss.ra.\"jboss.ra.quartz-ra\"]",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Product.ear\".\"Product-ejb.jar\".component.ImageUploadMDB.CREATE is missing [jboss.ra.quartz-ra]"
    ] }
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here and I can't seem to find any recent documentation on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**My MDB Code:**

```
@MessageDriven(name = "UpdateReleasePlansMDB", messageListenerInterface = org.quartz.Job.class,
    activationConfig = {@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "cronTrigger", propertyValue = "0 0 6 ? * MON")})
@ResourceAdapter("quartz-ra.rar")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class UpdateReleasePlansMDB implements Job
{
    public UpdateReleasePlansMDB()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
    {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
```